# Preserve row order in bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, wpf, vb.net, t-sql

I'm trying to bulk insert a table from a text file and preserve the row order. I'm doing this for two reasons:

- I need to check if the first row is a header, and remove it if so
- I am reporting back "errors"(differences between what a column value should be and what was given i.e. a letter in an alphanumeric field), and need to tell them which row in the text file they occurred at. At the same time I need to still insert these rows, just with blank values on the columns that have errors.

To do the bulk insert I am first inserting it into a temp table, and then inserting the cleaned up values into the main table. But the temp table seems to be in a random order.

The input file is not in any particular order, so I can't solve this with an order-by query.

Any suggestions on what I can do here?

Comment: You're using the wrong tool. SSIS is designed for this purpose, but it is a complicated tool. And the idea that you will report back "errors" makes no sense - unless you were planning on inserting into a table of string columns and then checking for datatype issues RBAR. Doing that in tsql will be extremely challenging.

Comment: @SMor this is in a WPF application. It needs to be ran offline and uses a local DB. Me reporting back "errors" does make sense as our auditors would like to know if there are blank fields, or letters where there should be numbers without combing through hundreds of thousands of records. I'm already doing this successfully using the method you described, just not reporting back the correct row number. The application runs very fast and works great aside from the row number issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the table or temp table you are inserting to, just have a column with the [IDENTITY PROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property)

```
create table #temp (ID int identity(1,1), otherColumn varchar(16), ...)
--do bulk insert
```

But, what may be more ideal for you is to create a unique row number in the source file.

Comment: I can't seem to add an identity to the temp table, because the columns are supposed to match up to the text document. I get a type mismatch error. Also if this is possible, would the identity match with the row number of the text file?

Comment: Looks like you can't use it with bulk insert. Thus, I'd just create the unique row number in the source data. If it's excel, this is easy. Or.... you can bulk insert into a temp. Move to another temp with identity, and do what ever work you want.

Comment: The identity of the second temp table would not match up with the rows on the text file. Adding a row number to the source data is not a feasible solution.

Comment: Very late response here, but I eventually did end up adding row numbers in the source file by duplicating it into a separate text file row by row.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with identity column, then bulk insert into a view on top of that table, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_TextFile (ID int identity(1,1), someColumn varchar(16))
GO

CREATE VIEW vw_TextFile
AS
SELECT someColumn
FROM tb_TextFile
GO

BULK INSERT vw_TextFile
FROM ...
```

Comment: You might need to add the ID as an  INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY to make the table have a clustered index.  (That's an easy way to create a clustered index at least from the example above.)  Adding the index and adding TABLOCK hint and using the view seems like a viable option.

Comment: FROM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms180876(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN: 

"In SQL Server 2005 and later versions, specifying TABLOCK on a table with a clustered index prevents bulk importing data in parallel. If you want to perform a parallel bulk import in this case, do not use TABLOCK. For more information about bulk loading in parallel, see Guidelines for Optimizing Bulk Import."

Comment: I used this idea successfully tonight to fix an out-of-order import of a text file.  The order mattered and there was no available key in the text file.  I added the PRIMARY KEY to the ID column to make sure it was the CLUSTERED INDEX and also added the WITH (TABLOCK) hint on the insert into the VIEW that only selected the NVARCHAR(MAX) column.  The view was a great tip, but I think the PK and the TABLOCK hint may also be necessary to guarantee that the order is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Using _con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
  _con.Open()
  If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Pkey)) Then
    deleteTbl = "Delete from " & destTableName & " WHERE " & Pkey & " = " & PkeyId
    Using cmdTable As New SqlCommand(deleteTbl, _con)
      cmdTable.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
  End If


  Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(_con)
    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0
    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 50000
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destTableName 'it is a tablename
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(sourceTable)  'sourceTable is a datatable
  End Using

End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Keying off of Christophej's suggestion with a few other additions:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.twrkImportFileLine ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, LineData NVARCHAR(MAX) ); 

GO

CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.vw_twrkImportFileLine AS
SELECT LineData
FROM twrkImportFileLine;

GO

--INSERT INTO vw_twrkImportFileLine (LineData) VALUES ('Test inserting text into the table through the view'); 
--SELECT * FROM vw_twrkImportFileLine
--DELETE FROM vw_twrkImportFileLine

BULK INSERT dbo.vw_twrkImportFileLine FROM '\\SERVERNAME\Import Folder\FileName.txt' WITH (TABLOCK) ;

SELECT LineData
FROM dbo.twrkImportFileLine 
ORDER BY ID;
```

The order was maintained in my 815 line sample file that I tested.  It was previously out of order without this method in large sections most likely due to parallelism.